# Organising Taxonomy categories

Tags: taxonomy

I have the following code in my sidebar to list all the taxonomy categories.

```
<div class="left">
    <h1>Categories</h1>

        <?php 
        //list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

        $taxonomy     = 'workcategories';
        $orderby      = 'name'; 
        $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
        $title        = '';

        $args = array(
          'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
          'orderby'      => $orderby,
          'show_count'   => $show_count,
          'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
          'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
          'title_li'     => $title
        );
        ?>

        <ul>
        <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
        </ul>
</div><!-- # END left -->
```

And this code outputs them in alphabetical order. Is there a way that I can order them however I like? My client wants them in a certain order and I have no idea how to do this.

Many thanks
E

Answer (score 1):

By what criterion do you need to order your taxonomy terms?

See this argument-array key:

```
'orderby'      => $orderby,
```

Per the documentation for [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), the `orderby` parameter can take the following values:

- `'ID'` - Default
- `'name'`
- `'slug'`
- `'count'`
- `'term_group'`

Note, you may also want to add the `order` parameter:

```
'orderby'      => 'ASC',
```

This parameter takes:

- `'ASC'`
- `'DESC'`

**EDIT**

> If I wanted to order them by ID - how would I go about that?

Using your code:

```
    <?php 
    //list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

    $taxonomy     = 'workcategories';
    // THIS IS THE PARAMETER TO CHANGE
    // CHANGE IT FROM 'name' TO 'ID'
    // (NOTE CASE)
    $orderby      = 'ID'; 
    // ADD THE 'order' PARAMETER, TO
    // SPECIFY WHETHER TO SORT ASCENDING
    // OR DESCENDING (AGAIN: NOTE CASE)
    $order        = 'ASC'   // 'ASC' for ascending, 'DESC' for descending
    $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $title        = '';

    $args = array(
      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
      'orderby'      => $orderby,
      // DON'T FORGET TO ADD THE 'order' PARAMETER HERE, TOO
      'order'        => $order,
      'show_count'   => $show_count,
      'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
      'title_li'     => $title
    );
    ?>
```

> The ID's don't run in numerical order you see.

Um, that doesn't make sense. IDs are *numerical*, because they are *integers*. Thus, ordering by `ID` results in an *ascending* or *descending* list of IDs, in numerical order.

Comment: If I wanted to order them by ID - how would I go about that? The ID's don't run in numerical order you see.

Comment: See updated answer, with `'orderby' => 'ID'` and `'order' => 'ASC'` integrated into your example code.

Comment: What I mean is that I want the IDs to run in this order - 4,5,18,7,10 - I've tried deleting the taxonmies and re-adding them to reset the order, but each time I re-add them they get the same ID numbers so I'm stuck with them.

Comment: "*What I mean is that I want the IDs to run in this order - 4,5,18,7,10*" - then that means that you're **not ordering the taxonomies by ID**; you're ordering them **arbitrarily**. You'll need to look into improving/changing your naming/organization schema, or else find a Plugin that allows for such arbitrary ordering.

Comment: How can I change the IDs for the taxonomies? I thought that by deleting them this would enable me to add them in the order that I want them in and new IDs would be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can't impose a manual ordering of categories natively in Wordpress.

The great thing about Wordpress is that it has a huge developer community behind it. A quick search gave me [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomy-sort/) that pretty much gives you exactly the feature you are looking for.